# Responsive menu with a dropdown as last Item

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a menu with some items, and at the end of this menu, it has a "Show More" dropdown. This "Show More" shows the rest of the items of menu, that could not be viewed because of the width of the browser. A classic responsive problem.

*To illustrate*:

[image]

And when the width is less than the image before, it happens:

[image]

So, my question is, what's the best way to do that? Is there any ready solution?

I am using Foundation, so I can't use any of another CSS module like Bootstrap. But, I can use jQuery, CSS3, HTML5. I don't have more limits than that - I guess =)

I got those images from [Instantcart](http://www.instantcart.com) website, so, you can go there to see it working.

Comment: try something first. then you if you got stuck at some point then ask a question. don't ask for the whole thing

Comment: I don't want the whole solution, I just want a good advice to do that, or if someone knows a ready solution fot that =)